# Is there a trident symbol in LaTeX?

Tags: symbols

I would like a trident symbol but there none to be found. The closest symbol I know is

```
\neptune
```

using the **wasysym** package. But it is not very nice (too 'ornamental' to my taste). Do you know some alternatives (something like the math mode version of \neptune, see http://milde.users.sourceforge.net/LUCR/Math/mathpackages/wasysym-symbols.pdf)
but without the circle it sits on?

EDT: The package **mathabx** has \Neptune too but it is even uglier IMHO

Comment: What about `$\Psi$` ;-)

Comment: Looks too much like $\Psi$ :)

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
\Neptune
```

from **marvosym**. Found it here: http://detexify.kirelabs.org/symbols.html

Comment: Definitely the most pretty I've seen so far, see http://ctan.mirror.rafal.ca/fonts/marvosym/doc/fonts/marvosym/marvodoc.pdf  but still too ornamental

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!